# Scheduling the created thread immediately

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, scheduling

i am using PsCreateSystemThread() for creating a thread. But it is not getting scheduled immediately. How can i force that thread schedule immediately after the creation of the thread.

Comment: Design away the need for this.

Answer (score 1):

Scheduling can be forced by [KeSetPriorityThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553265%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and/or [KeSetBasePriorityThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553246%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).